# Dynamic Schema in Monoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a product schema, there I want to set pricing which will be in different currencies as show below, but confused how will I dynamically create currency. There can be one currency, or even more.

```
{
    "pricing": {
        "inr": {
            "mrp": 999,
            "salePrice": 499
        },
        "usd": {
            "mrp": 999,
            "salePrice": 499
        }
    }
}
```

Here, there are 2 currencies, inr and usd, and thats what I need dynamic, it can be anything.

Basically I need to get data like **pricing.usd.mrp** in my NodeJs app. Thanks!

Comment: To define such a schema you could used `pricing` as [`Mixed`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) schema type, which can have the aribitrary currency information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mongoose custom object type to store as many currencies you want. But, keep in mind that the values of currencies get changed on seconds basis. So I don't recommend storing it like that. Instead, store only one value, like `priceInUsd` then when the user queries the item, use an [API](https://fixer.io/) to convert the `priceInUsd` value into other currencies.